# How to change color-scheme on BitBucket?

Tags: bitbucket

I remember long ago there is option to change color-scheme for source on BitBucket. But I cannot find it any more. Any one notice this? Or I just damn miss it? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct that you could chose your preferred Pygments theme on Bitbucket. The feature has been removed — David Chambers [explained in a mail to the Google group](http://groups.google.com/group/bitbucket-users/msg/141540987e2d156d) that the feature was backward since it could be customized on a per-repository basis, not a per-user basis.

There is a [related issue](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/3047/dark-themes-for-viewing-source) in their bug tracker that you might want to subcribe to or comment on. You can of course also try opening your own issue there or you could write to the mailinglist.